# I need index path for both section and row in tableview, I got a index for row but not for the section

Tags: ios

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCellrow", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellrow
        cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: namearr[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row])
        cell.lblName.text = namearr[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]
        cell.btnCross.tag = indexPath.row
        
        cell.btnCross.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cutt), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: What does `.1` represent? And what is `namearr`?

Comment: var namearr = [("Vegtable",["cauliflower","radish"],["Cauliflower","Radish"]),("Fruit",["grapres","mango"],["Grapres","Mango"]),("FLower",["lily","marigold"],["Lily","Marigold"])]

Comment: and .1 represent the section index path

Comment: Hi, did any of the answers solve your question? If so, please accept it by checking the box under the vote count. Otherwise, let us know if you have any problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you wanna store both `row` and `section` in button tag so it can be accessed in `cutt` function.

You can do it like this:

```
cell.btnCross.tag = (indexPath.section << 16) | indexPath.row
```

And then retrieve it in `cutt` func like this:

```
let section = button.tag >> 16
let row = button.tag & ((1 << 16) - 1)
```

Also note, that storing data in UIView tag is not the best solution in terms of performance.

UIKit implements tags using `objc_get/setAssociatedObject()`, meaning that every time you set or get a tag, you’re doing a dictionary lookup. Check out more [here](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html)

An other option, which is I'd say is better in terms of architecture too, is moving touch handling into the `Cell`, like this:

```
class TableViewCellrow: UITableViewCell {
    var btnCrossTapHandler: (() -> Void)?
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCross: UIButton!

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        initialize()
    }
    
    private func initialize() {
        btnCross.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cutt), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func cutt() {
        btnCrossTapHandler?()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.btnCrossTapHandler = { [weak self] in
        // you have indexPath here
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tuples in a datasource array. This is very bad practice.

Create a custom struct like

```
struct Section {
    let title : String
    let items : [String]
}

let namearr = [Section(title: "Vegtable", items: ["cauliflower","radish"]),        
              Section(title: "Fruit", items: ["grapres","mango"]),
              Section(title: "FLower", items: ["lily","marigold"])]
```

The capitalized names can be simply created with

```
let section = namearr[indexPath.section]
let name = section.items[indexPath.row]
let capName = name.capitalized
```

---

For the tag I recommend a calculation *section * 100 + row*

```
func tag(for indexPath : IndexPath) -> Int {
   return indexPath.section * 100 + indexPath.row
}
```

and the other way round

```
func indexPath(for tag : Int) -> IndexPath {
   return IndexPath(row: tag % 100, section: tag / 100)
}
```